# I've misconfigured Windows so that Metro apps are no longer shown in the Alt+Tab switcher. How can I undo my mistake?

Tags: windows-8.1, modern-ui, alt-tab, windows-store, system-preferences

By default, Windows 8.1 shows both Metro apps (Windows Store apps) and desktop apps in the Alt+Tab switcher. However, I have somehow changed some setting so that Metro apps are no longer shown in the switcher. I don't know how to fix the problem. Does anyone know where the relevant setting is?

Comment: I have this problem too. When I start a Metro app and press alt-tab, it is visible in the list of apps, but when I switch to another program, and then press and hold alt-tab again, the metro app is no longer listed.

When I do this with the Calendar app, and then type "Win-key calendar" to start it again, I get right back to where I was, so I think it is still running, just invisible.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution. In Windows 8 , the option was in a more obvious place (if i remember correctly), but in 8.1 it has been moved to:

<kbd>Win</kbd> → Search for "*Corner and edge settings*" → Select "*Allow switching between recent apps*"

This seems to restore the metro tabs to both the taskbar and the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher

Answer (score 1):

There's a registry value that can set the Alt-Tab switcher back to a legacy mode:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTabSettings

This is usually created manually to enable the legacy behaviour, but if it's present on your system you could try backing it up then deleting it.

I'd rather post this as a comment as I'm not sure it will fix your problem, but I don't have the reputation yet!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since blue_note's answer worked for me, I won't try editing the registry this time.